# Thesaurus Application

Tags: java

I need to implement a thesaurus application in Java which will retrieve the synonyms of the user's input.

Comment: "retrieve the synonyms". That's more of a thesaurus application :P

Answer (score 4):

If the user input is a word then do something like:

1. Create a Hashtable that uses the word for its Key
2. Store the synonyms in a List or String array
3. Add the Key and synonyms to the hash table
4. When the user inputs a word print the list associted with that key

I am assuming this is homework and you will be hard coding the dictionary and synonyms

Comment: Remember to put some rude words in there; they are the first ones that anyone looks at when they get a new dictionary

Answer (score 2):

do a dictionary.com search on the word and scrape the synonyms..

Answer (score 0):

Build a quick application to take the search string and call a synonym web service - [like this one](http://watson.kmi.open.ac.uk/API/explain-syn.html).

Answer (score 0):

"retrieve the synonyms"

Where are you getting the synonyms?  Are they stored in a DB/file, hard-coded?  Or do you need to get retrieve them yourself from an external service?

If you already have a list of synonyms, populate a HashMap and key the list of synonyms with the search word.